# Invoking VS custom tool from msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, resources, resx, .net-micro-framework

I have a [.NET Micro Framework](http://www.netmf.com) project that contains a *.resx embedded resource file.

In VS, the custom build tool is set to *ResXFileCodeGenerator* (seems to be a .NET Micro Framework specific version as the generated code is of [low quality](https://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/2329) and has [concurrency bugs](https://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/2330)).

This custom build tool is run when the *.resx file is changed through Visual Studio. It is not run when the *.resx file is changed from outside Visual Studio or when the project is built. The tool is also run when the *.resx file is right clicked and "Run custom tool" is selected.

This is a problem, because I would like to build the project via msbuild.
Having outdated *.Designer.cs files is not something nice to have in that environment ;-)

- How can I invoke a custom tool like *ResXFileCodeGenerator* from msbuild?
- If this is not possible: Where can I find documentation about how this ResXFileCodeGenerator works? How can I invoke it manually from command line?
- How does the ResXFileCodeGenerator deduce the numeric identifiers that are generated in the Designer.cs file?

  ```
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  internal enum BinaryResources : short
  {
      SomeBinaryResource = -7023,
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all build tools for NETMF are provided with the NETMF source code. You might want to look at the build tasks in the [.NETMF source](http://netmf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#client_v4_3/Framework/Tools/)

The tools are located in `client_(version)/Framework/Tools/`

The configuration of the build tasks is located in [client_(version)/tools/Targets](http://netmf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#client_v4_3/tools/Targets).

Comment: Thanks. The build tasks were very insightful :-) See `GenerateIdFromResourceName` in `GenerateResource.cs`.